# How can I validate a salt minion's key fingerprint before accepting it on the master?

Tags: salt-stack

When I build a new server, I collect the ssh key fingerprints from the console before my initial connections over the network using ssh. I'd like to be able to get the same out-of-band assurance when using salt.

With salt, when a new minion starts up it generates an RSA key and submits a request to the salt-master. I can use `salt-key -p <newminion>` to see the entire key and compare that with the minion's `/etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pub`, but I'd rather use the shorter fingerprint that `salt-key -f <newminion>` displays.

How can I get the minion to display its own key fingerprint? The minion doesn't have the `salt-key` command ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Run salt-call in local mode on the minion asking for [key.finger](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/commit/d8ba95ddb1e469600c735316a1aeafa115399b3c):

```
salt-call --local key.finger
```

If your salt is old or you otherwise don't have [key.finger](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/commit/d8ba95ddb1e469600c735316a1aeafa115399b3c), you can use cat, grep and md5sum as noted in [issue 3706](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/3706):

```
cat /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pub | grep -v -e BEGIN -e END | md5sum
```

Comment: The key.finger method is explained also in the [SaltStack Walk-through](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/walkthrough.html)